# How to change the text of html tag on button click in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have button when clicked on Select Equipment button have to change text of an html i of that particular div section and display the text as complete and also the class as complete.The following code is shown above:

```
<div>
        <div></div>
        <button OnClick='change(this);'>Select Equipment</button>
        <i class="open">Open</i>

</div>

function change(items) {  
 var divClicked = $(items).parent();
 divClicked.find('i.open').attr('class','complete').html('Complete');
}
```

this code was actually working earlier but it is not working now.Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: is there any console error ?

Comment: Include JQuery CDN  in Page

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Once check by replace your script with my script with included cdn

Comment: Not working,,,.

Comment: actually it was working before redesign of the website ..but it is not working now

Comment: there are many console errors ...cant understand which one

Comment: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

Answer (score 0):

### Include JQuery in Page

```js
function change(items) {  
 var divClicked = $(items).parent();
 divClicked.find('i.open').attr('class','complete').html('Complete');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <div></div>
        <button OnClick='change(this);'>Select Equipment</button>
        <i class="open">Open</i>

</div>
```

Comment: I have included this code in my file  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html:

```
<div>
<div></div>
<button id="btn">Select Equipment</button>
<i class="open">Open</i>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $(this).next('i').html('Close');
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/15/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $(this).next('i').html('Closed');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div></div>
<button id="button">Select Equipment</button>
<i class="open">Open</i>
</div>
```

First you need to add the jquery and the write the code to handle the click event .
Here When click the button the text associated with  will be changed.